# Почему нету файла .sln?

Tags: unity3d

Создавал новый проект, создал скрипт, и заметил что не работает автодополнение и подсветка. Посмотрел - в проекте не сгенерировался файл .sln. Пересоздал проект - та же проблема. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Какая версия Unity? Для Visual Studio установлены средства работы с Unity? Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вопрос решен. В настройках не был выставлен редактор.

Comment: тогда ответьте на свой вопрос и пометьте его как правильный, чтобы Дух сообщества не поднимал этот вопрос в будущем :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках нужно установить редактор, тогда должен появится файл .sln